# AutoHotKey SystemBeep on keypress

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to write an AHK script which gives an alarm beep when a user presses F1 to enter the help screen for a certain program. I can get the SystemBeep okay, but if the HotKey is programmed for F1 it doesn't open Help.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

1. user presses F1
2. systembeep
3. Help window opens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ~ prefix to the hotkey.

~ - means that the [hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) native function is not blocked

```
~F1:: 
    msgbox,hi! ; this gets executed and F1 command is still send to windows
return
```

Comment: Fantastic, cheers @dexter4712345! I knew there would be a simple way to do it :D